# Get the image associated with an ImageView

Tags: android, android-widget

I like to know whether there is any way by which we could get to know which image is associated with a particular imageview.

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(r.drawable.pic);
```

If this was like this i could have know that imageview iv conatins "pic". But this is not the case in my app.

Recently i have been developing an app in which i have 26 imageview,and i use to set the images associated which each of these imageviews randomly. That is, I couldnt know predict which imageview will contain which image.

But i need to find out which image is actually associated which each imageview. I also have 26 images, one for each imageview.

Answer (score 0):

How about when you set the tag to something you know:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView)whatever;
image.setTag("key", "Image ID");
```

then

```
String imageId = (String)imageView.getTag("key");
```

---

```
ImageView iv12=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2); 
ImageView iv13=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3); 
// ..............iv36....... 
Random ran=new Random(); 
for (int i = image.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 
    int index = ran.nextInt(i + 1); // Simple swap 
    int a = image[index]; 
    image[index] = image[i]; 
    image[i] = a; 
}
//.......................... 
final Drawable d1 = getResources().getDrawable(image[0]); 
final Drawable d2 = getResources().getDrawable(image[1]);
```

ok

```
// Then I assume
iv1.setImageResource(d1); // ?
iv1.setTag("key", image[0]);
```

Comment: @Joe-Actually i cannot set a tag because am not associating an image to an imageview directly...the images are randomly associated to the imageviews...

Comment: Why not? When you set the image, randomly or not, you can set the tag.

Comment: @Phix-i will show u the code am working on..plz tell me how to set the tag for the image..after seeing the code you will get the idea about the confusion am facing now....

Comment: ImageView iv12=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
         ImageView iv13=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
..............iv36....... Random ran=new Random();
         
         for (int i = image.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      {
        int index = ran.nextInt(i + 1);
        // Simple swap
        int a = image[index];
        image[index] = image[i];
        image[i] = a;
      }..........................   final Drawable d1 = getResources().getDrawable(image[0]);
         final Drawable d2 = getResources().getDrawable(image[1]);
       ...................so many

Comment: Can i use the following line of code to check whether the imageview contains a particular image-if(imageviw.getDrawable().equals(R.drawable.aaa))
    {
     
    }

Comment: No, they aren't comparable unfortunately.